# Tkinter Showing Message Too Early

Tags: python, tkinter

So I've been having a weird bug with Python and Tkinter where a message box pops up too early. I don't know what's wrong: it should be working, right?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

with open("passwords.passwords", "a+") as f:
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x1000")
    root.wm_title("Info Collect")

    mylist = []

    var1 = StringVar()
    var1.set("Application:")
    label1 = Label(root, textvariable=var1, height=2)
    label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    var2 = StringVar()
    var2.set("Password:")
    label2 = Label(root, textvariable=var2, height=2)
    label2.grid(row=0, column=3)

    ID1 = StringVar()
    ID2 = StringVar()
    box1 = Entry(root, bd=4, textvariable=ID1)
    box1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    box2 = Entry(root, bd=5, textvariable=ID2)
    box2.grid(row=0, column=4)


    def get_info():
        f.write("{0}: {1} ".format(box1.get(), box2.get()))

    def output_info():
        messagebox.showinfo(f.read())

    buttonA = Button(root, text="Save info", command=get_info, width=8)
    buttonA.grid(row=0, column=2)
    buttonB = Button(root, text="Output info", command=output_info(), width=8)
    buttonB.grid(row=0, column=5)

    root.mainloop()
```

That is all the code, do I have to do anything to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
buttonB = Button(root, text="Output info", command=output_info(), width=8)
```

to

```
buttonB = Button(root, text="Output info", command=output_info, width=8)
```

with parenthesis, the function is called and the returned value will be set to `command`, when you remove parenthesis you pass the function itself to `command` to be called when the button is clicked

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know I put those there.

Comment: Actually if you can help me again it won't read the file under messagebox.showinfo(f.read) where it returns empty.

Comment: because when you open the file with `a+` mode you might need to `f.seek(0)` to read from start, I suggest you take your code out of `with open()` and open the file only for reading/writing in the functions

Comment: Thank you again! Another error on my end where I was doing f.read() as the title of the popup!